# Any tool that can help me convert an XML file to a docx file?

Tags: html, xml, docx, converters

Im trying to convert an XML file to a docx file, Do you know of any tool/open source that can help me achive this or may be convert XML to X - and convert X to docx?

Comment: Show us an example of your XML: is it data oriented or a document oriented format?

Answer (score 1):

You could use python docx, it allows you to write any content to a docx file. You can use xml.etree to extract the information from xml file.
[XML.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)
[Python docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)